# Variable defined despite condition should prevent it

Tags: ruby, undefined, variable-assignment

Today I came across an interesting piece of code. It's more like a scientific question about the ruby parser.
We know everything in ruby is an object and every expression evaluates at least to `nil`.
But how is the following "assignment" parsed:

```
somevar
 NameError: undefined local variable or method 'somevar' for main:Object
somevar = "test" if false
 => nil
somevar
 => nil
```

You see the variable is undefined until it's used in the assignment. But the assignment is not happening because of the condition. Or is it happening because the condition evaluates to nil? I tried something which would break in this case, but it just works:

```
a = {}
a[1/0]
 ZeroDivisionError: divided by 0
a[1/0] = "test" if false
 => nil
```

So is this meant to work the way it is? Or does it make sense to test the variable (`defined?(somevar)`) before accessing, in case a future version of ruby will break this behaviour? As example by saving the assigned pointer to this variable.
My currently used ruby version is 3.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior in Ruby. Quote from the [Ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variables+and+Methods):

> The local variable is created when the parser encounters the assignment, not when the assignment occurs:
>
> ```
> a = 0 if false # does not assign to a
>
> p local_variables # prints [:a]
>
> p a # prints nil
> ```

Comment: Thank you :D. Shame on me I wasn't able to find this part in the docs. Even there is almost the same example :/

Answer (score 0):

If you do `= "test" if false` it evaluates to `nil` => no assignment needed. But by calling `somevar = ...` you told the interpreter to declare the name `somevar`. The `nil` aren't the same (if that makes sense).

The `[]` operator however doesn't declare a variable (only accesses) but since `if false` isn't true there is no assignment so the whole left side isnt evaluated.

Consider:

```
a = [1,2,3]
a[1] = "test" if false
a
=> [1,2,3]
```

`a[1]` is neither nil nor test.

Not sure what you expect or how future Ruby will break this?

Comment: The piece I was missing, was the point where the interpreter creates the variable.
To explain the reason I was thinking it could break in future: When you define this variable, there is a reference in memory which is never used. It's a very small one, still it could get "optimized". But as spickermann points out it's expected and documented behaviour. So I can savely use it :D